# Complex query with Rails 3.X

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

I have this db schema :

```
                 |-- comment
       |-- Post -|-- comment
       |
       |         |-- comment
User --|-- Post -|-- comment
       |
       |         |-- comment
       |-- Post -|-- comment
```

What is the best way to retrieve all comments belonging to one user ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can us a [has_many :through](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_many-through-association) association.

```
class User
  has_many :posts
  has_many :comments, :through => :posts
end

class Post
   has_many :comments
   belongs_to :user
end

class Comment
  belongs_to :post
end
```

With that structure you can simply do:

```
user.comments
```